# How to activate GCP FREE TIER?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to create a Google Cloud Platform free tier (e2-micro instance). I activated my account to premium usage and I still have my free credits. The problem is that when I want to create one free tier it shows me mothly costs, event if Google claims that it's free.

On YT videos, it shows them a little note "This tier is free for 744 hours a month", but I don't have nothing similar...

Pls, help. How to turn the free tier function on without being charged?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZabT.png)

Answer (score 2):

The free tiers are per billing account. The compute engine console can't know all the project linked to the billing account and if the free tiers is already used by another related project.

Therefore, the UI show you the worse case. But, in the billing page (after a day for instance) you will see the cost of your VM, with a discount on it. Thus it's free at the end!